# Reading CSV file into a list of class c#

Tags: c#

I've attempted to read a CSV file into a list of my class with no luck. Here's the CSV file:

```
id,firstname,username,email
1,Thomas,tjones,tjones@test.com
2,Jake,ajake,ajake@test.test.dk
3,Juliet,jlit,jlit@test.dk
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    List<User> users =
        File
            .ReadAllLines("Data/users.csv")
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(v => User.FromCSV(v))
            .ToList();

    public void displayList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(users);
    }

    public User(int id, string firstname, string username, string email)
    {
        Id = id;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Username = username;
        Email = email;

        if (Firstname is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Firstname cannot be null", nameof(firstname));
        }
        else if (Lastname is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Lastname cannot be null", nameof(lastname));
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public static User FromCSV(string csvline)
    {
        string[] values = csvline.Split(',');
        User information = new User();

        information.Id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        information.Firstname = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
        information.Username = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
        information.Email = Convert.ToString(values[3]);

        return information;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to call the `displayList();` in my main function, only `id` pops up, but I thought I skipped the first line with `Skip(1)`.

Comment: Apparently you have some extra white space at the beginning of the file.

Comment: ReadAllLines is putting one rows into the list which contains all the data.  You are not splitting the rows into separate lines.

Comment: @jdweng: Not according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0) for ReadAllLines.

Comment: This code is not compilable. Even after fixing some minor issues the call to  _.Select(v => User.FromCSV(v))_  made everytime one builds a user object leads to a StackOverflowException

Comment: If the return character isn't a Windows return (linux).

Comment: And in any case the line _Console.WriteLine(users);_ should print out the name of the class not an _id_ string

Comment: There's no need to do a `Convert.ToString(` on something that is a string already.

Comment: @omic96, In general its safer to use third party software when parsing CSVs e.g CSVHelper, there are alot of minute details which aren't taken care of e.g escaping when you do things they way you are

Comment: Your constructor has a `if (Lastname is null)` check, but `Lastname` doesn't exist. Can you please make sure that your code is a [mcve]?

Comment: It worked fine after making these changes. Remove references to lastname, add a parameterless constructor, comment out method `public void displayList()` and move this code to console `Main` method `List<User> users = File.ReadAllLines("Data/users.csv").Skip(1).Select(v => User.FromCSV(v)).ToList();`. A code to initialise a list of `users` makes more sense outside `User` class, otherwise it creates a list of user for each user and again for each user in method `User.FromCSV`. This is driving crazy your CPU.

Comment: You are recreating the wheel.  CSVHelper will already create an `IEnumerable<T>` for you  and has already solved problems you havent run into yet.

Comment: What about serializing the csv file into json, then deserializing into the class? Would this not work well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told by Steve, your code will leads into a StackOverflowException.
Why that? Because you're populating the users list each time someone creates a new instance of the User class. But inside the method that creates the list, you create a new instance of the User... So this start a loop that will never ends.

I changed a bit your code and in my environment it works:

```
namespace Stack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var users = File.ReadAllLines("Data/users.csv")
                            .Skip(1)
                            .Select(v => FromCSV(v))
                            .ToList();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id} - {user.Firstname}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        static User FromCSV(string csvline)
        {
            string[] values = csvline.Split(',');
            User information = new User();

            information.Id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
            information.Firstname = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
            information.Username = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
            information.Email = Convert.ToString(values[3]);

            return information;
        }
    }



    public class User
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
}
```